# Code Academy: How to make this Soundcloud API example to work IRL

Tags: javascript, html, css, soundcloud

I tried putting the exact .html and .js codes online and hosting it myself.

I want to replicate this example: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-intermediate-en-txGOj/0/2?curriculum_id=50ecb9bedc5e3250c40000c6

You can view my code at www[dot]whatsgucci[dot]com/cloudstalk.html

Here's thee code I used:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stalkstyle.css"/>
        <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
        <script src="stalkscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="results">

        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#results {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: cursive;
}
```

JS:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: '5e3fe3759c70fe637cb15bab22e238e0'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  SC.get('/tracks', { genres: 'festival trap' }, function(tracks) {
    $(tracks).each(function(index, track) {
      $('#results').append($('<li></li>').html(track.title + ' - ' + track.genre));
    });
  });
});
```

But nothing ends up appearing

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly did you add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

your example is currently broken with out adding jquery. you have to add jquery above the soundcloud sdk import like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stalkstyle.css"/>
        <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
        <script src="stalkscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="results">

        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

you can see your working example here: 
http://runnable.com/UzetnvwmO3pX9Eiq/code-academy-how-to-make-this-soundcloud-api-example-to-work-irl

Answer (score 0):

Include Jquery library in your code

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`